# How can I increase the quota YouTube Data API v3

Tags: youtube-api

YouTube Data API v3
Quota: Queries per day
Current limit: 10,000

How can I increase the quota of my API?

[image]

Comment: What happened when you read and followed the instructions in the image you've provided? Right there, is clearly where the answer lies. Click the link, contract the sales team, pay some $$. Is this question about avoiding the $$ step?

Comment: The $$ step may be free cf https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota If you want a temporary solution as Google is slow AFAIK you can give a try to my no key system at https://yt.lemnoslife.com

Answer (score 1):

If you have reached the max quota you can request additional quota. by submitting the [YouTube API Services - Audit and Quota Extension Form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form)

You can read all about this in the [YouTube Data API - Quota and Compliance Audits](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/quota_and_compliance_audits) documentation page.

Just make sure to click extension request at the top.

[image]

[Intro to YouTube API and cost based quota.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHUGuw1Agnc)

Answer (score -1):

The screenshot says it all: You are already using the maximum allowed daily API calls allowed by your subscription plan. If you still need more than that, you need to pay for an upgrade of your subscription.

Comment: Where exactly does it state that you need to pay for additional quota for the YouTube api.  This must be really new i have been using this api for 10 years and never had to pay for a quota extension.   I would love to hear how big of a quota extension you applied for if they charged you for it.   It would be interesting to hear what the threshold is.