# YouTube Data API v3 Queries per day Quota limit with trial

Tags: google-cloud-platform, youtube-api

I have the following question maybe someone can help me:

I just started with implementation of a youtube upload python script. I want to upload a certain amount of videos with api. I created me a google cloud account and connected the YouTube Data API v3. After playing a little bit around I always run into the quota limit.

> googleapiclient.errors.ResumableUploadError: <HttpError 403 when
> requesting None returned "The request cannot be completed because you
> have exceeded your [quota](/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota).". Details:
> "[{'message': 'The request cannot be completed because you have
> exceeded your [quota](/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota).',
> 'domain': 'youtube.quota', 'reason': 'quotaExceeded'}]">

I already researched a little and found [How can I increase the quota YouTube Data API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73359390/how-can-i-increase-the-quota-youtube-data-api-v3) and the link to https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form.

My first question is: Right now, I do not even see the possibility to change the quota. I think it is due to the "free trial" account I have right now.

[image: Quota Screen]

[image: No possibility to change]

How can I change it to a regular account? And how high is the probability that the youtube team extends the quota to a 6-digit amount?

Thx in advance

Comment: Google uses many factors when reviewing a quota increase. You must ask for a quota increase to find out, unfortunately. In my experience, until you have several months of `paid` billing history or you are a business, some quota requests are declined.

Answer (score 1):

YouTube api has a development quota of 10000 quote points per day.

A video upload costs in quote points 1600 if I recall.

You have run out of quote points wait until midnight west coast USA and your quote will rest

This has nothing to do with your account this is standard until you apply for a quote increase